# React with MapBox GL: how to add sources in the ComponentDidMount() method?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I'm trying to follow this blog article, https://blog.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js-react-764da6cc074a, to build a `create-react-app` app with MapBox GL. I'm trying to render the following `Map` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3VydHBlZWsiLCJhIjoiY2p6cnVneWdvMHlzeDNqcWo0dm83ZzZ2eiJ9.yUCSreTRcKs12uT5PTCztg';


export default class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11'
    });

    this.map.on('load', function() {
      this.map.addSource('overlay', {
        'type': 'image',
        'url': 'https://trailmapper.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/YOSEmap2_300res.png',
        'coordinates': [
          [-119.68780746975982, 37.76972057166063],
          [-119.61609218185251, 37.76972057166063],
          [-119.61609218185251, 37.6106678317546],
          [-119.68780746975982, 37.6106678317546]
        ]
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.map.remove();
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      width: '100%'
    };

    return <div style={style} ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />;
  }
}
```

Without these lines,

```
this.map.on('load', function() {
  this.map.addSource('overlay', {
    'type': 'image',
    'url': 'https://trailmapper.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/YOSEmap2_300res.png',
    'coordinates': [
      [-119.68780746975982, 37.76972057166063],
      [-119.61609218185251, 37.76972057166063],
      [-119.61609218185251, 37.6106678317546],
      [-119.68780746975982, 37.6106678317546]
    ]
  });
});
```

the app renders fine, but with them, I get the following error:

[image]

I have read about the necessity of binding event handlers to `this` in React (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), but I'm not sure whether that applies here as `this.map` is an object, not a function.

How can I modify this component to get it to load the source?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the `target` of the `UIEvent`, which is the `map`:

```
this.map.on('load', function(e) {
  e.target.addSource('overlay', {
    'type': 'image',
    'url': 'https://trailmapper.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/YOSEmap2_300res.png',
    'coordinates': [
      [-119.68780746975982, 37.76972057166063],
      [-119.61609218185251, 37.76972057166063],
      [-119.61609218185251, 37.6106678317546],
      [-119.68780746975982, 37.6106678317546]
    ]
  });
});
```

(The map still fails to load because of the CORS policy, but that's a separate issue).